# RemoteControlClient putbitmap() crashes the app

Tags: android, metadata, android-music-player

In my mediaplayer app, if the user continuously skip the songs the app crashes and am getting the following error

> android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:923) 
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388) 
>                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183) 
>                                                                                               **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't parcel a recycled bitmap**
>                                                                                                  at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkRecycled(Bitmap.java:393)
>                                                                                                  at android.graphics.Bitmap.writeToParcel(Bitmap.java:1669)
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1357)
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1262)
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:638)
>                                                                                                  at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313)
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1096)
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:663)
>                                                                                                  at android.media.MediaMetadata.writeToParcel(MediaMetadata.java:408)
>                                                                                                  at android.media.session.ISession$Stub$Proxy.setMetadata(ISession.java:426)
>                                                                                                  at android.media.session.MediaSession.setMetadata(MediaSession.java:411)
>                                                                                                  at android.media.RemoteControlClient$MetadataEditor.apply(RemoteControlClient.java:591)
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                                  at com.xxxxxxxxx.musicplayer.RemoteControlClientCompat$MetadataEditorCompat.apply(RemoteControlClientCompat.java:389)

here's the block of code which write metadata information

```
BitmapDrawable mAlbumArt = Myclass.getArtwork(this, mMusicPath, true);
        if (mAlbumArt.equals(null))
            mAlbumArt = (BitmapDrawable) (this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sym_albumart_noimage));


mRemoteControlClientCompat.editMetadata(true)

.putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, getArtistName())
                .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUMARTIST, getArtistName())
                .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, getAlbumName())
                .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, getTrackName())
                .putLong(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, getDuration())
                .putLong(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_CD_TRACK_NUMBER, getSongID())
                .putBitmap(
                        RemoteControlClientCompat.MetadataEditorCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTWORK,
                        mAlbumArt.getBitmap())
                .apply();
```

If I remove 
**.putBitmap(
RemoteControlClientCompat.MetadataEditorCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTWORK,
                        mAlbumArt.getBitmap())** this issue is getting fixed.I've tried all questions related to **Can't parcel a recycled bitmap** What am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether bitmap got recycled or not before writing to metadata.

```
if(!mAlbumArt.getBitmap().isRecycled())
        mRemoteControlClientCompat.editMetadata(true)
                .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, getArtistName())
                .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUMARTIST, getArtistName())
                .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, getAlbumName())
                .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, getTrackName())
                .putLong(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, getDuration())
                .putLong(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_CD_TRACK_NUMBER, getSongID())
                .putBitmap(
                        RemoteControlClientCompat.MetadataEditorCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTWORK,
                        mAlbumArt.getBitmap())
                .apply();
```